# Can I limit the number of outbound messages per month in Twilio?

Tags: sms, twilio, message

Yeah, apparently the title explains everything.

Could I configure the count of messages per month?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can use the [Usage Triggers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-triggers) API to have Twilio notify you when a certain number of messages have been sent on a monthly basis.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-triggers#create-a-new-usagetrigger-with-params

Hope that helps.